# Actualizar orden de compra de base de datos luego de recibir aprobacion de pago (MercadoPago)

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un eccomerce fake en fase de desarrollo, estoy implementando el checkout pro mp  cree una api con node js, y consumo los datos con react, mi base de datos esta en mongodb y tambien uso moongose, el problema radica en que no encontre manera para actulizar el status de la orden de pediente a rechazado/aprobado en la base de datos. Ya tengo los datos despues de hacer la peticion get con el id de la operacion, asi que puedo ver el status, y todos los datos de la operacion. Con lo que obtengo de respuesta ya podria pasarlos del lado del cliente y que los muestre, pero mi problema es (como si no puedo hacer un post o un put, decirle a la base de datos, actualiza el status a aprobado, etc).

```
const getPayment = async (req, res) => {
  let url = req.query
  let id = req.query.payment_id

  const response = await getService(id)
  let status = response.status;
  res.json(response)
 }

Aca ya tengo todos los datos en esta funcion, ahora como le paso a la base de datos el campo del status para que actualice?
```

La ruta del getService es de mercadopago y de ahi mp me pasa los datos de la operacion, una vez que le paso el id.

```
const ENDPOINT = `https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/${id}`;
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {Schema, model} = mongoose;

const orderSchema = new Schema(
    {
        items:[],
        state: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        city: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        address: { type: String, required: true, trim: true},
        height: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          trim: true
        },
        userId:{type: String, required:true, trim:true},
        shippingPrice:{type:Number, required:true, trim:true}, 
        paymentStatus:  { type: String, required: true, trim: true}
      },
      {
        timestamps: true,
        versionKey: false,
      }
)

module.exports = model("Order", orderSchema);
```

aca recibo el pago, o sea es de tipo post.

```
const createPayment = async (req, res) => {
  
  const items = req.body;
 
  let result = await getOrderAmount(items.cart, items.myShipping)

  const response = await mercadopago.preferences.create(result.preference);
  const initPoint = response.body.init_point;
  const id = response.body.id;
  
  const newOrder = new Order({
    
    items:response.body.items,
    state:response.body.shipments.receiver_address.state_name,
    city:response.body.shipments.receiver_address.city_name,
    address:response.body.shipments.receiver_address.street_name,
    height:response.body.shipments.receiver_address.street_number,
    userId:items.myShipping.userData,
    paymentStatus:'pending',
    shippingPrice:response.body.shipments.cost 
  })
  result = await newOrder.save();

  let fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
  
  res.json(({ statuscode: 200, message: "product found", id, initPoint }))
  
};
```

Comment: Hola Facu. Necesitariamos ver un poco más de código. Cómo te estás conectando a la base de datos?

Comment: Hola @Fede7501, tengo un modelo order, ahi guardo los items que me llegan de la preferencia, tengo un paymentStatus, que cuando hago el post para el pago lo guarde a mano como pendiente, es un string.

Comment: Me parece que te estaría faltando agregarle un campo `paymentId` (o como quieras llamarlo) al `orderSchema` que te permita relacionar el pago con la orden y en la función `getPayment` podrías hacer un `Order.update({paymentId: id}, {$set: {paymentStatus: status}})`

Comment: cuando llamas a la api esta te resulve con una url que debes pasar a cliente este hace el pago y te manda a una pagina de exito o fin donde te acusan los resultados de las operaciones y muchas api te permiten chequear esa data internamente, creo que es un problema de leer bien el manual de la API.

Comment: Hola @Fede7501 muchas gracias por tu ayuda. No encontre un parametro para relacionar la respuesta que me devuelve la preferencia, y la respuesta que me devuelve el pago final, por ejemplo el client_id de la preferencia es el id de mi aplicacion que genere en mp, y el client_id del pago ese si creo que es el id del pagador o payer. Pero resolvi el inconveniente guardando la orden en el getpayment, de esa manera creo poder ratrear la orden en base al id de cada comprador de mp. Muchas gracias.